# How to plot a nice Lorenz Curve for factors in R (ggplot ?)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, distribution

I need a nice plot for my thesis on the different distributions of different factors. Only the standard approach seemed with the `package(ineq)` was flexible enough.

However, it doesn't let me to put dots (see comment below) at the classes. It is important to see them, ideally to name them individually. Is this possible?

```
Distr1 <- c( A=137, B=499, C=311, D=173, E=219, F=81)
Distr2 <- c( G=123, H=400, I=250, J=16)
Distr3 <- c( K=145, L=600, M=120)

library(ineq)
Distr1 <- Lc(Distr1, n = rep(1,length(Distr1)), plot =F)
Distr2 <- Lc(Distr2, n = rep(1,length(Distr2)), plot =F)
Distr3 <- Lc(Distr3, n = rep(1,length(Distr3)), plot =F)

plot(Distr1,
     col="black",
     #type="b",      # !is not working
     lty=1,
     lwd=3,
     main="Lorenz Curve for My Distributions"     
     )

lines(Distr2, lty=2, lwd=3)
lines(Distr3, lty=3, lwd=3)

legend("topleft",
       c("Distr1", "Distr2", "Distr3"),
       lty=c(1,2,3),
       lwd=3)
```

This is how it looks now
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the problem, only `Distr1` is needed; it' good to strip down before posting.

```
library(ineq)
Distr1 <- c( A=137, B=499, C=311, D=173, E=219, F=81)

Distr1 <- Lc(Distr1, n = rep(1,length(Distr1)), plot =F)
plot(Distr1$p,Distr1$L,
     col="black",
     type="b",      # it should be "b"
     lty=1,
     lwd=3,
     main="Lorenz Curve for My Distributions"     
)
```

Comment: Thank you much. I added the line wrongly inside the post. For me it doesn't work, even with quotes. Have executed the code?

Comment: Well, yes, because I found the bug in your code. "Does not work": I recommend `fortunes::fortune("exploded")` (you need the fortunes package).

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain how to use it?

Answer (score 9):

In case you really want to use `ggplot`, here is a simple solution

```
# Compute the Lorenz curve Lc{ineq}
  library(ineq)
  Distr1 <- c( A=100, B=900, C=230, D=160, E=190, F=40, G=5,H=30,J=60, K=500)
  Distr1 <- Lc(Distr1, n = rep(1,length(Distr1)), plot =F)

# create data.frame from LC
  p <- Distr1[1]
  L <- Distr1[2]
  Distr1_df <- data.frame(p,L)


# plot
  ggplot(data=Distr1_df) +
    geom_point(aes(x=p, y=L)) +
    geom_line(aes(x=p, y=L), color="#990000") +
    scale_x_continuous(name="Cumulative share of X", limits=c(0,1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(name="Cumulative share of Y", limits=c(0,1)) +
    geom_abline()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As there is a package (`gglorenz`) handling Lorenz Curves automatically for ggplot, I add this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gglorenz)

Distr1 <- c( A=137, B=499, C=311, D=173, E=219, F=81)
x <- data.frame(Distr1)

ggplot(x, aes(Distr1)) + 
  stat_lorenz() + 
  geom_abline(color = "grey")
```

[image]